# AngularJS how to get the element scrollHeight value?

Tags: angularjs

I am writing angularJS directive, in this directive I want to get the select list box scrollHeight value in angularJS, but it is undefined.

How can I get this value please? I can get this value in jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside your directive link function:

```
app.directive("scrollHeightDetector", function() {
     return {
       restrict : "AEC",
       link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
           // here you can use element to get the height

           var height = element[0].scrollHeight;


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  it works. why it works use element[0] but got undefined when call element.scrollHeight directly?

Comment: jamie2015: element here is a jQuery (or jqLite) object which responds to array indexing. The actual DOM object is the first item in the array.